# Problem with add an attribute to Customer in magento 2

Tags: database, upgradeschema, installdata

I created a module in this way:
I created a vendor folder "Test1" Then I created a module folder "AddCustomerAttr" then a folder inside the module "etc" and inside "etc" I put module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Test1_AddCustomerAttr" setup_version="0.0.2">
</module>
```

Then I created registration.php:

```
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Test1_AddCustomerAttr',
__DIR__
);
```

Then I created "Model" folder and "Attribute" folder inside it and then I created 3 folders inside "Attribute":
"Backend" "Frontend" and "Source"

Inside of each folder, I created a file Attribute.php

/Backend/Attribute.php:

```
 namespace Test1\AddCustomerAttr\Model\Attribute\Backend;

 class Attribute extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
 {
 /**
 * Validate
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $object
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 * @return bool
 */
public function validate($object)
{
    $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
    if ( ($object->getAttributeSetId() == 10) && ($value == 'wool')) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('Bottom can not be wool.')
        );
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

/Frontend/Attribute.php:

```
 namespace Test1\AddCustomerAttr\Model\Attribute\Frontend;
 class Attribute extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend
 {
 public function getValue(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object)
 {
    $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
    return "<b>$value</b>";
}
}
```

Then I created a Setup folder inside module folder and I put file InstallData.php inside it:

InstallData.php:

```
namespace Test1\AddCustomerData\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
  private $eavSetupFactory;

  public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
  {
      $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
  }

  public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {
      $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
      $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'test_attribute',
        [
            'group' => 'General',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Test Attribute',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Test1\AddCustomerAttr\Model\Attribute\Source\Material',
            'frontend' => 'Test1\AddCustomerAttr\Model\Attribute\Frontend\Material',
            'backend' => 'Test1\AddCustomerAttr\Model\Attribute\Backend\Material',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 50,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true
        ]
    );
  }

}
```

Then I run command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

But no change occurred in customer page!

I did these modules on Product Model and It correctly worked!

I also tried these instructions: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html
But still I don't know what is the problem and it didn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

To add customer attribute follow this step:

Namespace\Module\Setup\InstallData.php

```
    <?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' =>999,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],//you can use other forms also ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Check Backend: 
[image]

For Frontend Override  vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml and add this

```
<div class="field custom_attribute">
    <label class="label" for="customer_attribute”><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Attribute') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" id="customer_attribute" name="customer_attribute" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('customer_attribute')->getValue()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Attribute') ?>" class="input-text" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Override vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

```
<div class="field custom_attribute”>
    <label class="label" for="customer_attribute"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Attribute') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" id="customer_attribute" name="customer_attribute" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCustomerAttribute()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Attribute') ?>" class="input-text" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
```

source: https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-customer-custom-attribute-in-magento-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

As Sameer Bhayani answered before, customer custom attribute should be assigned to an attribute set, also specifying 'used_in_forms' data you will add the attribute to those forms.